What is $\left[ \begin{array}{c} K_i;0\\ \ell\\ \end{array} \right] _{\varepsilon _i}$ in the restricted specialization in QUE algebras?
I have a question about the book A Guide to Quantum Groups written by Vyjayanthi Chari and Andrew Pressley. It comes from section $9.3$ on page $300$ of this book
In Section 9.1, the authors define the algebra $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(q)$ where $\mathfrak{g}$ is a finite-dimensional complex Lie algebra. Let $\mathbb{A} =\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$, they define $U^{res}_{\mathbb{A} }$ and $U^{res}_{\varepsilon}=U^{res}_{\mathbb{A} }\otimes_{\mathbb{A} }\mathbb{Q}(\varepsilon)$. Here $\varepsilon $ is a primitive $\ell$th root of unity, where $\ell$ is odd and greater than $d_i$ for all $i$.
Let $$\left[ \begin{array}{c}
    K_i;0\\
    s\\
\end{array} \right] _{q_i}=\prod_{r=1}^{s}{\frac{K_iq^{1-r}-{K_i}^{-1}q^{r-1}}{q_{i}^{r}-q_{i}^{-r}}}.$$ Then in page $300$ remark $[1]$, the author write an element
$\left[ \begin{array}{c}
    K_i;0\\
    \ell\\
\end{array} \right] _{\varepsilon _i}\in U_\varepsilon^{res}$ .
Here is my question:
If I replace $q_i$ with $\varepsilon_i$, because $\varepsilon^l=\varepsilon^{-l}=1$, then there will have $0$ in the denominator.
So I am very confused about it. How should I deal with $\left[ \begin{array}{c}
    K_i;0\\
    \ell\\
\end{array} \right] _{\varepsilon _i}$?
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

You are correct and your observation is precisely the point. It is all about choices. You define the K-symbol as an element in the quantum group over $\mathbb{Q}(q)$. At a later point you more or less define $U_\mathbb{A}^{res}$ as being generated as $\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$-module by by a specified set of elements (such that this definition is compatible with product and coproduct etc). If you then specialize to $\varepsilon$, by definition the K-symbol stays and is nonzero, while for example
$$(\varepsilon^\ell-1)\left[ \begin{array}{c}
    K_i;0\\
    \ell\\
\end{array} \right] _{\varepsilon _i}\in U_\varepsilon^{res}$$
specializes to zero, even though as a polynomial in $q$ it looks more innocent.
More prominent and maybe more transparent is this for another generator: the divided power $E_i^{(n)}$. Because we choose $E_i^{(n)}$ as a generator of $U_\mathbb{A}^{res}$  as $\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$-module, it specializes to something nonzero, while $E^n=[n]_q!  E_i^{(n)}$ specializes to zero. Had we chosen $E^n$ as generator, then it would specialize to something nonzero and $E_i^{(n)}$ would be undefined (i.e. not contained in $U_\mathbb{A}^{res}$ altogether). This choices are called restriced versus unrestricted specialization. Something similar has been previousley done for Lie algebras in finite characteristic
Concretely, you make all your computations over $q$, then you rewrite everything in terms of K-symbols and divided powers ("grouping singular terms") and then you specialize and see what the remaining polynomials in $q$ do. See G. Lusztig: Quantum groups at unit of 1.

Thank you for your answer. I might have understood something. Does this mean that when we calculate something,  we should firstly consider it  in the case of $q$, and then reduce it into the form of these $K$-symbol and  divided power generators, and  finally replace $q$ with $\epsilon$ ?

$\left[ \begin{array}{c}
K_i;0\
\ell\
\end{array} \right] _{\varepsilon _i}$ is just a special element. This does not mean replacing $q$ with $\varepsilon$ and then we get an undefined element?

To both: Yes, completely. The K-symbol is a special element, and an arbitrary element is a combination of such elements, with coefficents with q-polynomials. The latter you  specialize, but you cannot specialize any q "inside" the K-symbol, in principle.
